# (PHP) Select Three random number without duplicate value

Tags: php, random

I have to get three random number from 1 to 3 without duplicate value in results
With: 

$total = '3';

$rand1 = rand(1,$total);
$rand2 = rand(1,$total);
$rand3 = rand(1,$total);
And results for ex: 1.2.3 or 3.2.1, or 2.1.3
Please help me, thanks in advance

Comment: Hows it random if the range is 1 to 3 and you want 3 numbers? Do they have to be whole numbers?

Comment: i want print 3 numbers such as: Three random number is 3 1 and 2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about shuffling the array, like so:

```
$num = range(1,$total); 
shuffle($num);
print_r($num);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try:

```
$inp = array(1, 2, 3);
shuffle($inp);
$rand1 = $inp[0];
$rand2 = $inp[1];
$rand3 = $inp[2];
```

Comment: Have a look at @AljoshaBre 's answer - it'll deal with any number of values.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [shuffle()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) function to permute an array with the number 1 to 3.
Shuffle places the elements in an array in a random order.

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array();   
$max_value = 10;
$count = 5; // must be less than $max_value of you'll get an infinite while loop
for ( $i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
    do {
        $value = rand( 1, $max_value );
    }
    while( isset( $values[ $value ] ) /* && count( $values ) < $count */ )
    $values[ $value ] = TRUE;
}

print_r( array_keys( $values ) );
```